# Collision Security

Tags: aes, cbc

Question concerning collision issue in CBC-mode:
If we are using CBC mode with AES for 1 message, the birthday paradox indicates that we risk a collision after 2^(n/2) so 2^64 plaintext of 128 bits of the message.

My question is: is there a similar result concerning the number of messages we can send with different IV but the same Key? Is it still 2^(n/2) different messages before security issues or is it something else?

Thank you

Comment: How do you define a "collision" for AES-CBC?

Comment: @MechMK1: For AES-CBC, a collision is the appearance of two different 128 ciphertext blocks that are exactly the same; such a collision allows an attacker to deduce the xor of the corresponding plaintext blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The "birthday bound" of $2^{64}$ ciphertext blocks applies whether the ciphertexts come from one huge message, or a large number of smaller messages - all the matters is that they were all encrypted with the same key.